# iPhone App won't run on ipad at 2x resolution

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

my iphone application keeps getting rejected because it won't run at 2x iphone resolution on the ipad. my application is an iphone only app but apple requires every app to run on the ipad.

here is the rejection letter i keep getting -iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: my resolution is off only for the ipad and i dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem of rejection. My app was iPhone app and Apple require it to run on iPad without any modifications.

It means that your app should run on iPad as it runs on the iPhone device without any modifications in design and other things.

My app was also running good on iPad without any modifications but still it was rejected. That was so frustrating for me. I searched lot for this but I haven't got any particular solution.

What I did for the solution:

1. Make sure your app runs on iPad as per the Apple's guidelines.
2. Make sure the splash screen should also run on the iPad device also.(It was the only reason for my app's rejection).
3. And in your app's "Note" section on iTunes connect mention that your app is only developed for iPhone only.(I think it's required to mention!!!)

Hope your app submitted successfully.